# add numbers with decimals in a listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

In my listbox, decimal quantities are stored and the total is stored in a textbox

but the problem is that the quantities taken with me ","

so by adding my listbox, does not take into account, the values ​​of the left side of the ","

example of what makes me 
12,3 + 6,7 + 2,1 = 21

and what I want to do 
12,3 + 6,7 +2,1 = 21,1

I have used this code

```
   Dim Total As Double 

   For x = 0 To lstIva.ListCount - 1 

   total = total + Val (lstIva.List (x)) 

   Next 

   txtTotal = total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems VBA type conversions don't recognise anything other than `.` as the decimal seperator.

One way to deal with this is to replace the `,` with `.`, do the sum, then substitute back `,`

Also, in case there are `.`'s as thousand seperators, remove them too.

```
Dim Total As Double
Dim x As Long
For x = 0 To lstIva.ListCount - 1
    Total = Total + (Replace$(Replace$(lstIva.List(x), ".", ""), ",", "."))
Next

txttotal = Replace$(Total, ".", ",")
```